# If $f(x) + x^2[f(x)]^3 = 10$ and $f(1) = 2$, find $f '(1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, functional-equations

> If $f(x) + x^2[f(x)]^3 = 10$ and $f(1) = 2$, find $f '(1)$.

I'm not entirely sure how to solve this problem. My first instinct would be to plug in a 2 for every $f(x)$ and then take the derivative, but that just gives me zero. Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Take the derivative of both sides: $f'(x)+2x\left(f(x)\right)^3+x^23\left(f(x)\right)^2f'(x)=0$ Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

Start with 
$$ f(x) + x^2 f(x)^3 = 10 $$
Take derivatives of both sides 
$$ f'(x) + 2x f(x)^3 + x^2 3f(x)^2 f'(x) = 0. $$
Set $x = 1$ in the last equation 
$$ f'(1) + 2f(1)^3 + 3f(1)^2 f'(1) = 0 $$
As $f(1) = 2$, we have
$$ f'(1) + 16 + 12 f'(1) = 0 \iff f'(1) = -\frac{16}{13} $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try differentiating the equation (implicitly). If this does not seem very obvious to you, try substituting $y=f(x)$ and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

If one assumes $f$ is differentiable near $x=1$ and if one assumes the first equality is an identity, then one may differentiate it to get
$$
f'(x)+2x \cdot [f(x)]^3+x^2 \cdot 3 \times f'(x)\cdot [f(x)]^2=0
$$ then putting $x:=1$ gives
$$
13f'(1)=-16.
$$